# How to get the following code to continue on error?

Tags: excel, vba

```
If CheckContractStart(MoreMemoryBlock(i)) <> "" Then
    Cells(RowCount + i, 3).Value = Format(DateValue(CheckContractStart(MoreMemoryBlock(i))), "dd MMM yyyy")
Else
    Cells(RowCount + i, 3).Value = "Missing"
End If
```

For the above expression,

I would only run the format() when it is not empty. However, I realized that sometimes the content may not be empty but contents non-formatable content such as "comments" or maybe even typos of date such as missing /. So, I am just wondering if there is a way to get the code to continue on error and just return a msgbox instead of stopping altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your code with On Error Resume Next ... On Error GoTo 0

```
On Error Resume Next
If CheckContractStart(MoreMemoryBlock(i)) <> "" Then
    Cells(RowCount + i, 3).Value = Format(DateValue(CheckContractStart(MoreMemoryBlock(i))), "dd MMM yyyy")
Else
    Cells(RowCount + i, 3).Value = "Missing"
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In VBA you can use the keywords `On Error`.

Those are only two uses but they are relevant to your question:

1) `On Error Goto Label` This will go to `Label` which you define by writing that label where you want your code to resume execution after an error by following it with a semi-colon `Label:`.

2) `On Error Resume Next` which will just completely ignore the error. You may want to have a little bit of error checking to make your code more stable but that is sometimes necessary and/or helpful to do so even though it can be dangerous.